# Mark items in Listbox 2 from selection in ListBox 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have two ListBox with some items in each. I have three tables, lets say, company, employee, company_employee

I populate the first ListBox with the company, second ListBox with employee. What I want is to select a company and when I do that, select what employee's that are connected to that company.

How can I do this with asp.net MVC 4? I thought of a ajax-solution to get the records in company_employee depending on my first listbox selection id, but im not sure how to do this with asp.net.

Any suggestions to lead me forward?

Best regards,

me.

Comment: Paste your effort so far to make it easier for someone to provide a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a jquery event triggered on a change of your first listbox that calls a webservice that will return a custom collection(employees) of type employee, this method will take in the country id perhaps . Bind that collection to a control. If you're expecting it all on a plate sorry but that is the way forward you can break this down and learn how to do each step.

Comment: Hmm, by webservice do you mean a ajax call to retrieve a custom collection from the controller?